# Qual o equivalente do argumento `hue` do seaborn no matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Quando quero que os pontos pertencentes a diferentes categorias sejam coloridos cada um de uma cor no `seaborn`, eu simplesmente coloco a variável categórica de interesse como valor do argumento `hue`. Exemplo replicável:

```
import seaborn as sns
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'salario': np.random.pareto(1, size = 100), 
'IQ' : np.random.normal(size = 100),
'Sexo' : np.random.binomial(1,0.5,size = 100)
}, index = range(100))

df['Sexo'].replace({0:'Masculino', 1:'Feminino'}, inplace = True)

sns.lmplot('IQ', 'salario', hue = 'Sexo', data = df, fit_reg = False)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria fazer isso no `matplotlib`, tem como?

Comment: tente isso, https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_demo2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-demo2-py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é o método `legend_elements()`, ver documentação [aqui](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements). Reescrevendo o código com `matplotlib`, temos:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'salario': np.random.pareto(1, size = 100), 
'IQ' : np.random.normal(size = 100),
'Sexo' : np.random.binomial(1,0.5,size = 100)
}, index = range(100))

df['Sexo'].replace({0:'Masculino', 1:'Feminino'}, inplace = True)

labels, index = np.unique(df["Sexo"], return_inverse=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
meu_scatter = ax.scatter(df['IQ'], df['salario'], marker = 'o', c = index, alpha = 0.8)
ax.legend(meu_scatter.legend_elements()[0], labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]